# How to reliably write to json files from different functions at the same time?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to run a gaming website that requires writing json data in Python 3 to a user dictionary. And now that users are starting to play frequently, Data is being written at the same time causing an error in the structure of the dictionary and i was wondering if there was any solutions to this issue like a queue system or a more reliable method?

CODE EXAMPLES:

```
# DICTIONARY FORMAT
{
    'User': {
        'Data': 999,
        'Nonce': 420
    }
}
# PYTHON DEFINITION
def example(user, number):
    with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
        example = json.load(f)
    example[user]['Data'] = example[user]['Data'] + number
    with open('example.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(example, f, indent=4)
```

The end result is just a structure error causing it to stop writing data at a certain point for some unknown reason and not closing the {}

Comment: Concurrent writes to the same file from different functions? Maybe you should refactor your application to use a database instead of a file.

Comment: Did you notice that your code has multiple syntax errors? Yes, you could use a queue in conjunction with multithreading or multiprocessing. A database is a superior option